# "XML is invalid" when Get-CimInstance is supplied with -ComputerName

Tags: xml, powershell

I've been googling around for a while but can't seem to find the right answer.

My laptop is part of an AD domain. I use it to explore/develop tools in PowerShell and WMI. I noticed whenever I Get-CimInstance on the Win32_ComputerSystem class with `-ComputerName`, I get the `XML is Invalid` error:

```
PS C:\Users\jsung> Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName jsung03-pc
Get-CimInstance : The WS-Management service cannot process the request because the XML is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName jsung03-pc
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem:String) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80338043,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
+ PSComputerName        : jsung03-pc
```

jsung03-pc is the hostname of my laptop. If I take out the `-ComputerName` argument, the query returns a result w/o any issue.

The same symptom occur on my laptop and desktop. Both are running Windows 7 SP1. I loaded RSAT 4.0 and .NET 4.5.2. WinRM and WsMAN were enabled via Enable-PSRemoting.

```
PS C:\Users\jsung> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1

PS C:\Users\jsung> Get-Service wi*
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  WinDefend          Windows Defender
Running  WinHttpAutoProx... WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Se...
Running  Winmgmt            Windows Management Instrumentation
Running  WinRM              Windows Remote Management (WS-Manag...
```

If I remove `-ComputerName jsung03-pc` the cmdlet returns a result w/o error:

```
PS C:\Users\jsung> Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
Name             PrimaryOwnerName         Domain                   TotalPhysicalMemory      Model                   Manufacturer
----             ----------------         ------                   -------------------      -----                   ------------
JSUNG03-PC       ntapadmin           <domain.com>            4147822592               4384BE6                 LENOVO
```

This issue is not shown in querying the "Win32_Process" class.

Test-WSMan shows the system is running 3.0.

```
PS C:\Users\jsung> Test-WSMan -ComputerName jsung03-pc -Authentication Default
wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 6.1.7601 SP: 1.0 Stack: 3.0
```

I ran the WMI Diagnosis Utility and tried to recover the repository via `cscript WMIDiag.vbs   WriteInRepository=Root` but still no luck. There is little to no info about `XML is invalid`.

Can anyone shed some light on what database may be corrupted and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using Get-WmiObject instead of Get-Ciminstance?

Comment: PS C:\Users\jsung> get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem -computername jsung03-pc


Domain              : hq.netapp.com
Manufacturer        : LENOVO
Model               : 4384BE6
Name                : JSUNG03-PC
PrimaryOwnerName    : ntapadmin
TotalPhysicalMemory : 4147822592

Comment: Whymarrh, Thanks for the advice!  Get-WMIObject works.

But, it's just that my laptop & desktop aren't much off the standard. What blocks Get-CimInstance -ComputerName to work from these Windows 7 hosts may block my tools from deployment. I'd like to get to the bottom of this issue. At least, we should be able to uninstall or repair any corrupted XML repository… Can't seem to find much help on the web.

Comment: Do you mind trying: Get-WSManInstance wmicimv2/win32_computersystem -SelectorSet @{name="jsung03-pc} and see if that returns without an error?

Comment: Any progress on this old issue? I am running into exactly the same issue right now and reproduce this issue exactly to your posted results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to surround the ComputerName in quotes? I've seen weird stuff like this happen when computer names have hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Bump,

I know this is an old post but, just in case you come across it. CIM uses https to communicate over ws-man, where as gwmi uses http. You can set the port to listening and modify it to your needs in order for it to work.

got it to work for me